# ¿por que no puedo mandar una imagen a una api en javascript usando fetch?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, multipart

tengo un problema quiero mandar una imagen desde un html en javascript hacia un api, el asunto es que pruebo en insomnia y lo puedo mandar sin problemas, solo coloco el body como Multipart y le agrego el nombre inputFile y elijo una imagen [imagen desde insomnia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9m7R.png)

en header tengo el token

este es mi código

```
<p>Foto:<input type="file" id="foto" required></p>
<p><button type="button" id="boton1" class="text-white">Subir foto</button></p>
<p><img id="imagen"></p>
<script>
    document.getElementById("boton1").addEventListener("click", () => agregar());


    function agregar() {
        let fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('inputFile', document.getElementById("foto").files[0]);
        console.log(fd)
        console.log(document.getElementById("foto").files[0])
        fetch('/uploadPerfil', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'token':'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2NzAyMjQ4MTQsImlhdCI6MTY3MDEzODQxNCwic3ViIjoxfQ.wsAFGxO8Orv_U4moUE1eDeWuJwtN9PgjLyYuds2RBTY'
            },
            body: fd
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(datos => {
                if (datos.resultado == "Ok")
                    document.getElementById("imagen").setAttribute("src", document.getElementById("foto").files[0].name);
            })
    }
</script>
```

por el momento el token lo coloco directamente para probar.

estos son los console log
el primero es del formData
el segundo de la imagen recibida
[impresiones en consola](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7f6U.png)

si pudiera alguien orientarme estaría muy agradecido

como mencione arriba intente cambiando lo que recibia el body: tambien intente cambiar fd.append donde dice inputFile, eh estado buscando en internet y no eh encontrado alguna guia de como manejar estos casos

este es el codigo de la api en flask la cual si puedo usar desde insomnia o postman pero no se como hacerla funcionar desde js

```
@imageUser.route('/uploadPerfil' , methods =['POST'])
@tokenCheck
def upload(usuario):
    print(usuario['user_id'])
    searchImage = Images.query.filter_by(user_id = usuario['user_id']).first()
    try:
        if searchImage:
            file = request.files['inputFile']
            data = file.read()
            render_file = render_image(data)
            searchImage.rendered_data=render_file
            searchImage.data=data
            db.session.commit()
            return jsonify({"message":"Imagen actualizada"})
        else:
            file = request.files['inputFile']
            data = file.read()
            render_file = render_image(data)
            newFile = Images()
            newFile.type="Perfil"
            newFile.rendered_data=render_file
            newFile.user_id=usuario['user_id']
            newFile.data=data
            db.session.add(newFile)
            db.session.commit()
            return jsonify({"message":"Imagen agregada"})
    except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
        print(e)
        return jsonify({"message":"Error"})
```

Comment: Puedes compartir código de la api?

Comment: hola el api es en flask 
lo dejo en edición a la pregunta

Comment: El error 400 BAD REQUEST te da más información al abrirlo?. Lo otro, estás seguro que el token lo estás enviando bien? Cómo lo enviaste desde Insomnia?

Comment: el error no dice nada mas y en el inicio de la pregunta agregue un link donde esta la imagen desde insomnia, la cual lo único diferente a un json normal es que es multipart y le mando la imagen como inputFile  igual gracias por tomarte tu tiempo para responder a mi pregunta.